# What is the appropriete way to handling exceptions inside a python method?

Tags: python, exception

Suppose I have a function and, depending on its inputs, it must "advise" the caller function that something went wrong:

```python3
def get_task(msg, chat):
    task_id = int(msg)
    query = db.SESSION.query(Task).filter_by(id=task_id, chat=chat)
    try:
        task = query.one()
    except sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound:
        return "_404_ error"
    return task
```

Notice at the except block I want to pass something that the caller function can handle and stop its execution if it's necessary, otherwise, it will return the right object.

```
def something_with_the_task(msg, chat):
   task = get_task(msg, chat)
   if task == "_404_ error":
       return
   #do some stuff with task
```

Comment: You should [`raise`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions) an exception and catch it in the caller function.

Comment: Define a higher-level more appropriate exception for your interface and `raise` it, given you have no way to recover from the lower-level failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already seem to know how exceptions work.

The best thing to do in case of an error is to `raise` an exception.

Returning some *magic* value is considered a bad practice, because it requires the caller to explicitly check for it, and a [hundred of other reasons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/166039/why-are-exceptions-considered-better-than-explicit-error-testing).

You can simply let the `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound` exception escape (by removing the `try:` and the `except:` block in `get_task()`), and let the caller handle it with a `try: ... except: ...` block, or, if you prefer to do some [hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding), you can define a custom exception:

```
class YourException(Exception):
    pass
```

and use it like this:

```
def get_task(msg, chat):
    try:
        task = ...
    except sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound:
        raise YourException('explanation')
    return task

def something_with_the_task(msg, chat):
    try:
        task = get_task(msg, chat)
        # do some stuff with task
    except YourException as e:
        # do something with e
        # e.args[0] will contain 'explanation'
```

Feel free to make the `YourException` class more informative by explicitly adding some attributes and a constructor to set those, if needed.

The default constructor makes a decent job however:

```
>>> e = YourException('Program made a boo boo', 42, 'FATAL')
>>> e
YourException('Program made a boo boo', 42, 'FATAL')
>>> e.args[0]
'Program made a boo boo'
>>> e.args[1]
42
>>> e.args[2]
'FATAL'
```

Comment: You could also use `except sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound as err: raise YourException('explanation') from err` to include the original exception in the traceback.